# Doing MEAN tutorial, inline HTML stops working when 'resolve' is introduced to $stateProvider state

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, express, mean-stack

Doing [this MEAN stack tutorial](https://thinkster.io/mean-stack-tutorial) which basically creates a rudimentary reddit-like clone with a main page showing all posts and, for each separate post, a separate page showing the post and its comments.

---

Everything worked great until I added the resolve property to the 'home' state of $stateProvider, which (as far as I understand) ensures that all posts are loaded from the database before the view is rendered. After I added resolve, the inline HTML for 'home', which prints out the main page, stopped working. If I comment 'resolve' out, it works again.

I have a hard time debugging this because I'm still learning how everything works (total beginner although I have a basic grasp of OOP).
Can anyone catch what's going on? If you want me to format this post better please let me know.

[Link to my Github with the code for this project](https://github.com/jussisaurio/MEANtutorial/tree/master/flapper-news)

The files that I have made edits to are:

**app.js** (i just added mongoose here)

**public/javascripts/angularApp.js** (angular module file)

**models/posts.js** (model for posts)

**models/comments.js** (model for comments)

**routes/index.js** (get/post requests etc)

**views/index.ejs** (main view file)

Here's the angular app javascript code (i have commented out 'resolve' here):

```js
var app = angular.module('flapperNews', ['ui.router']);

<!-- POSTS-service -->

app.factory('posts', ['$http', function($http){
 
 // create object o with an array called posts
 var o = {
  posts: [] 
 };
 
 o.getAll = function() {
  
  return $http.get('/posts').success(function(data) {
   
   // copy the received data into object o's posts array
   angular.copy(data, o.posts); 
  }); 
 };
 
 return o;
}]);




app.config([
 '$stateProvider',
 '$urlRouterProvider',
 
 function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
  
  $stateProvider 
   
   .state('home', {
    url: '/home',
    templateUrl: '/home.html',
    controller: 'MainCtrl'
    
    /* resolve: {
     postPromise: ['posts', function(posts){
      return posts.getAll();
        }]
      } */
    
    })
   
   .state('posts', {
    url: '/posts/{id}',
    templateUrl: '/posts.html',
    controller: 'PostsCtrl'
    })
   
   
   
   
   
  $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('home');
 }
]);



<!-- MAIN CONTROLLER -->

app.controller('MainCtrl', ['$scope', 'posts',

function($scope, posts) {
   
  $scope.posts = posts.posts; 
  <!-- 2way binding eli servicen array päivittyy myös -->
    
  $scope.addPost = function() {
   
   if(!$scope.title || $scope.title == '') { return; }
   
   $scope.posts.push({
    title: $scope.title, 
    upvotes: 0, 
    link: 
    $scope.link, 
    comments: [
     {author: 'Joe', body: 'Cool post!', upvotes: 0},
     {author: 'Bob', body: 'Great idea but everything is wrong!', upvotes: 0}
  ]
  
 });
   $scope.title='';
   $scope.link='';
   
  };
  
  $scope.incrementUpvotes = function (post) {
   
   post.upvotes += 1;
  };
  
}]

);





<!-- POSTS CONTROLLER -->
app.controller('PostsCtrl', ['$scope', '$stateParams', 'posts',

function($scope, $stateParams, posts){
 
 // fetch post with correct ID from posts service and save it into $scope.post
 $scope.post = posts.posts[$stateParams.id];

}]);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the following:

```
resolve:{
   posts: "posts"
}
```

And then you can use posts as a dependency in your controller. Alternatively you can just make an $http call in the resolve object to return the promise like this and pass the result into the angular controller.

```
posts:  function($http){
            return $http({method: 'GET', url: '/postt'})
               .then (function (data) {
                   return doSomeStuffFirst(data);
               });
         },
```

Comment: For  more details read this: https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep current structure in return of posts factory (and not to get only http.data reponse), you can use $q like this:

```
app.factory('posts', ['$http', '$q', function($http, $q){
  var deferred = $q.defer();

  // create object o with an array called posts
  var o = {
    posts: [] 
  };

  o.getAll = function() {

   $http.get('/posts').then(function(data) {
      // copy the received data into object o's posts array
      angular.copy(data, o.posts);
      deferred.resolve(o);
    }); 
  };

  return deferred.promise;
}]);
```

In this case, you'll get full o object in return of promise (using .then function), so you'll be able to reuse this data.